# Rails 3 + Select2 multiple ids + AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 to make an AJAX call to select users for a simple messaging system within my app. Gotten most everything to work (even InitSelection via AJAX), except I've been tearing my hair out trying to do what seems to be an easy thing: iterate through multiple user IDs to create a message for each.

The problem, apparently, is that Select2 returns the multiple ids as a string, instead of an array that Rails expects. I've tried a bunch of things don't seem to work....

How do I convert the string:

```
{"username" => "78,21,12"}
```

to

```
{"username" => [78,21,12]}
```

Comment: how about this assuming your variable is named hash `hash.map{|a,b| {a=> b.split(',')}}`

Comment: @ant, Could I do that in a form submission?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you're saying. See what I ended up with below...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after much googling, I finally got the rather simple answer. This code now resides in my application controller for any string that needs converting for Select2 purposes:

```
def s_to_array(string)
  result = [string[0..-1].split(',').collect! {|n| n.to_i}].flatten
end
```

Hope this saves others the time I spent... :)

For the sake of clarity, I call this from the create action in the controller:

```
     def create
        messaged = (params[:message][:username])
        body = (params[:message][:body])
        subject = (params[:message][:subject])
        msg_group = s_to_array(messaged)
        sanitized = Sanitize.clean(body, Sanitize::Config::BASIC)

        msg_group.each do |u|
          @message = Message.new
          @message.subject = subject
          @message.sender = @user
          @message.recipient = User.find(u)
          @message.body = sanitized
          @message.save
        end
    ....
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution :

```
h = {"username" => "78,21,12"}

h.map{|a,b| {a=> b.split(',')}}.reduce(:merge)
```

Produces :

```
 {"username"=>["78", "21", "12"]}
```

Or if you want integers instead of string :

```
h.map{|a,b| {a=> b.split(',').map(&:to_i)}}.reduce(:merge)
```

Produces :

```
{"username"=>[78, 21, 12]}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Might have mislead you with the simple hash. That's just part of the (much deeper) form params. So I extracted the "username" values (string = params[:message][:username]) and applied the below within the create action, which worked.

Comment: @awvidmer can you give sample input/output

Comment: Don't know exactly what you're looking for, but this is the structure of the params :Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1xdBYp4TmOybkHfXuOMAQgim2N3kthqPLUjFI+o++Rk=", "message"=>{"username"=>"73,71", "subject"=>"Test", "body"=>"test"}, "user_id"=>"remdivwa"}